# Configuration Properties by @Autowired is null in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a properties class

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = ShiroProperties.SHIRO_PREFIX)
public class ShiroProperties {
  public static final String SHIRO_PREFIX = "shiro";

  private String urlLogin;
  private String urlSuccessed;
```

and a Configuration class

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties({ ShiroProperties.class })
public class ShiroConfig implements ApplicationContextAware {

  ApplicationContext applicationContext;
  @Autowired
  private ShiroProperties shiroProperties ;
```

shiroProperties is null, but i can find it value in ShiroConfig used

```
applicationContext.getBean(ShiroProperties.class)
```

my Application class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Bootstrap {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Bootstrap.class, args);
  }
}
```

So weird, i can run success with similar code in other project, but this.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think you should add `@Component` to `ShiroProperties` (according to [Spring Boot Externalized Configuration Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html))

Comment: I saw that before, and i tried it, but it didn't working. Anyway, thank you

Comment: i found the reason for this odd problem, if add `LifecycleBeanPostProcessor` annotated by `@Bean`, then `@Autowired` is not working. `LifecycleBeanPostProcessor` class is from shiro.

Answer (score 1):

I met this same issue as @Dean said,I had done is put the `LifecycleBeanPostProcessor`  bean is another configure class ,and configure other Shiro in another configuration class ,see below example:

```
@Configuration
public class ShiroLifecycleBeanPostProcessorConfig {

    /**
     * 
     * 
     * @return
     */
    @Bean(name = "lifecycleBeanPostProcessor")
    public LifecycleBeanPostProcessor getLifecycleBeanPostProcessor() {
        return new LifecycleBeanPostProcessor();
    }

}
```

The main Shiro Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@AutoConfigureAfter(value = ShiroLifecycleBeanPostProcessorConfig.class)
public class ShiroConfiguration {

    public static final String cacheFile = "encache.xml";
    private static final String active_cache_name = "activeSessionCache";

    @Autowired
    private RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate;

    /**
     * 
     * 
     * @throws UnknownHostException
     */
    @Bean(name = "shiroFilter")
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    public ShiroFilterFactoryBean shiroFilterFactoryBean(DefaultWebSecurityManager securityManager)
            throws UnknownHostException {
        ShiroFilterFactoryBean shiroFilterFactoryBean = new ShiroFilterFactoryBean();

        shiroFilterFactoryBean.setSecurityManager(securityManager);

        shiroFilterFactoryBean.setLoginUrl(ShiroSecurityUrls.LOGIN_PAGE);
        // shiroFilterFactoryBean.setSuccessUrl(ShiroSecurityUrls.LOGIN_SUCCESS_URL);
        shiroFilterFactoryBean.setUnauthorizedUrl("/error");

        Map<String, Filter> filters = new LinkedHashMap<String, Filter>();
        LogoutFilter logoutFilter = new LogoutFilter();
        logoutFilter.setRedirectUrl(ShiroSecurityUrls.LOGIN_PAGE);
        filters.put(DefaultFilter.logout.name(), logoutFilter);
        shiroFilterFactoryBean.setFilters(filters);

        Map<String, String> filterChainDefinitionManager = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

        filterChainDefinitionManager.put("/static/**", DefaultFilter.anon.name());
        filterChainDefinitionManager.put("/node_modules/**", DefaultFilter.anon.name());
        filterChainDefinitionManager.put("/pages/**", DefaultFilter.anon.name());

        filterChainDefinitionManager.put(ShiroSecurityUrls.LOGIN_PAGE, DefaultFilter.anon.name());
        filterChainDefinitionManager.put(ShiroSecurityUrls.LOGOUT_URL, DefaultFilter.logout.name());
        filterChainDefinitionManager.put(ShiroSecurityUrls.REGISTER_PROCESS_URL, DefaultFilter.anon.name());
        filterChainDefinitionManager.put("/**", DefaultFilter.user.name());

        shiroFilterFactoryBean.setFilterChainDefinitionMap(filterChainDefinitionManager);

        return shiroFilterFactoryBean;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * 
     * @throws UnknownHostException
     */
    @Bean(name = "securityManager")
    @DependsOn(value = { "ehCacheManager", "rememberMeManager", "sessionManager", "credentialsMatcher" })
    public DefaultWebSecurityManager securityManager(EhCacheManager ehCacheManager, RememberMeManager rememberMeManager,
            SessionManager sessionManager, CredentialsMatcher credentialsMatcher) throws UnknownHostException {
        DefaultWebSecurityManager securityManager = new DefaultWebSecurityManager();
        // 1. Cache Support
        securityManager.setCacheManager(ehCacheManager);
        // 2. Session Support,inject the cacheManager from securitymanager
        securityManager.setSessionManager(sessionManager);
        // 3. Rememberme Support
        securityManager.setRememberMeManager(rememberMeManager);

        // 4. JDBC,LDAP Realm implements
        Collection<Realm> authorizingRealms = Lists.newArrayList(shiroDatabaseRealm(credentialsMatcher),
                shiroActiveDirectoryRealm(credentialsMatcher));
        securityManager.setRealms(authorizingRealms); // inject the cacheManager
                                                        // from securitymanager
        if (securityManager.getAuthenticator() instanceof ModularRealmAuthenticator) {
            ModularRealmAuthenticator modularRealmAuthenticator = (ModularRealmAuthenticator) securityManager
                    .getAuthenticator();
            modularRealmAuthenticator.setAuthenticationStrategy(new FirstSuccessfulStrategy());
        }

        return securityManager;
    }
}
```

Hope this code helps you ,thanks.

Comment: hi, thank you for your solution, i already changed framework to Spring Security, and i know the actual problem what is it, the property with @Autowired will be successful inject if use public instead private

Answer (score 0):

This being another configuration class for your application should be decorated with `@Configuration` annotation to enable a bean creation and injection into the context for wiring from another classes.

Comment: sorry, i don't understand what you mean

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. All I meant is to update your class as `@Configuration 
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = ShiroProperties.SHIRO_PREFIX)
public class ShiroProperties {
  public static final String SHIRO_PREFIX = "shiro";

  private String urlLogin;
  private String urlSuccessed;`

Answer (score 0):

In common,  **AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor** set such property annotationed by @Autowired in the phase when Spring load FactoryBean classes. If the following factory beans:

1. ApplicationContextAwareProcessor
2. ApplicationListenerDetector
3. ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor
4. PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker
5. CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor

refer your config bean, your bean will not be autowired properties after creation due to AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor is not loaded.

For example, properties is null and throw NullPointerException

```
@Component
public class BeanFactoryTest {

@Autowired
private IdGenProperties properties;

@Bean
public SnowflakeServer snowflakeServer() {
    System.out.println(properties.getBaseUrl());
    return null;
}

@Bean(name = "conversionService")
public ConversionServiceFactoryBean getConversionService() {
    ConversionServiceFactoryBean bean = new ConversionServiceFactoryBean();
    Set<Converter> converters = new HashSet<>();
    converters.add(new StringToDateConverter());
    bean.setConverters(converters);
    return bean;
}

public static class StringToDateConverter implements Converter<String, Date> 
{
    public Date convert(String source) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        try {
            return sdf.parse(source);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with adding @Component in your ShiroProperties.class

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = ShiroProperties.SHIRO_PREFIX)
public class ShiroProperties {
  public static final String SHIRO_PREFIX = "shiro";

  private String urlLogin;
  private String urlSuccessed;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, It's not working, added ``@Component`` will throw NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException, in other word, ``@ConfigurationProperties`` already create bean in Spring Context

Comment: try with removing applicationContext.getBean(ShiroProperties.class);