# custom yaml properties not available in service class

Tags: spring-boot

My application.yaml:

```
spring:
  profiles: test
mysvc:  
   server: https://myserver.com
   user: john123
   passwd: pass123!
```

My application.java class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Autowired
    MySvcProps mySvcProps;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

    }
      @Override
        public void run(String... args) {
            System.out.println(mySvcProps.getServer());
        }
}
```

My properties class:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="mysvc")
public class MySvcProps{

    private String server;
    private String user;
    private String passwd;

    // setters/getters
}
```

My service class:

```
@Service
public class MySvc {
        @Autowired
        MySvcProps mySvcProps;

public void printServer() {
    System.out.println(mySvcProps.getServer());
}
```

in the Application class, no problem I can access the method in mySvcProps and get the values. But in MySvc class, mySvcProps is null.

All classes share same base package name, why would the autowire not work in MySvc class?

Comment: Did you try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42484412/configuration-properties-by-autowired-is-null-in-spring-boot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was only able to get it to work following this doc:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-yaml

Update my service with a constructor that accepts an autowired mySvcProps fromt the caller:

```
    @Service
    public class MySvc {

    private final MySvcProps mySvcProps;

        @Autowired
        public MySvc (MySvcProps mySvcProps) {
            this.mySvcProps= mySvcProps;
        }

        public void printServer() {
            System.out.println(mySvcProps.getServer());
        }
    }
```

Not sure why this it works like this.